# Add Customs column to Admin > sales > order

Tags: magento

i am try to add columns in Admin > sales >order by overriding app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

add this code in protected function _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")')));
```

add this code in protected function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
    'index' => 'name',
));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

copy this code and pest 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
working fine in 1.8.1

http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team 
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

/**
 * Retrieve collection class
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getCollectionClass()
{
    return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('total_qty_ordered'));
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = billing.parent_id AND billing.address_type="billing"',array('billing.postcode AS bp', 'billing.city AS bc', 'billing.email AS be', 'billing.telephone AS bt',));
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',array('method'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

   $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Id'), //Order #=order id
    'width' => '30px',
    'type'=> 'text',
    'index' => 'increment_id',
    'filter_index' => 'main_table.increment_id',
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased'),
            'index'     => 'store_id',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id',
            'type'      => 'store',
            'width'      => '30',
            'store_view'=> true,
            'display_deleted' => true,
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.billing_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.shipping_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
        'index' => 'base_grand_total',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.base_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
    'index' => 'total_qty_ordered',
    'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.total_qty_ordered',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('bp', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pincode'),
    'index' => 'bp',
    'width' => '60px',
    'filter_index'  => 'billing.postcode'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('bc', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('City'),
    'index' => 'bc',
    'width' => '60px',
    'filter_index'  => 'billing.city'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('be', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('E-mail'),
    'index' => 'be',
    'width' => '60px',
    'filter_index'  => 'billing.email'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('bt', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Mobile'),
    'index' => 'bt',
    'width' => '60px',
    'filter_index'  => 'billing.telephone'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('color', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Colors'),
        'index'     =>'color'
    ));
   $this->addColumn('size', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Sizes'),
        'index'     =>'size'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('method', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Method'),
    'index' => 'method',
    'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_payment.method',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
    }
    $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
        ));
    }

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
    ));

    return $this;
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    return false;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
```

}